# Find minimum polynomial $p$ multiple of $(x^2+1)$, such that p-1 is multiple of $(x^3+1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

This is exercise four, chapter two, of the book "Algebra Lineal y Geometría" from Castellet and Llerena.

So far, I can see that $i$ is a root of $p$ and $-1$ one of $p-1$. Which means that $p(i) = 0$ and $p(-1) = 1$. After some computation, I can also see that $q(i) = -1/(1-i)$, where $p(x)+1 = (x^3+1) * q(x)$. I can see that the degree of $p$ is bigger than three. However, I wasn't able to infer much more. I tried guessing possible values with very little success. The question also doesn't specify the domain of $x$ and I fear I might have gone into a rabbit hole by playing with complex numbers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  -  x^{2}  -  x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$

or

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right)    =  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  -  x^{2}  -  x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) \; \;  -1    $$

==============================

What follows [is the Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm); where most people prefer  "back-substitution," I write in the style of a continued fraction.

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) } +  \left(   -  x  + 1 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   -  x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   -  x  - 1 \right) } +  \left( 2  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   -  x  + 1 \right)  =  \left( 2  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   -  x  - 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   -  x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right) }{ \left(   -  x  - 1 \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x^{3}  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  -  x^{2}  -  x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$

Comment: Ah, I feel like an idiot now. Thank you so much, this was very helpful.